# minimal polynomial of squared operator

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

let $V$ be a vector space over the field $F$, and $T:V \to V$ a linear operator. prove that the minimal polynomial of $T^2$ is of degree lower or equal to the minimal polynomial of $T$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, izikgo. Is there any feedback to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $p(X)\in F[X]$ be the minimal polynomial of $T$ and define $$q(X):=p(X)p(-X)\in F[X].$$
Try to show that $q(X)=r(X^2)$ for some $r\in F[X]$. Then $\deg r=\deg p$ and $r(T^2)=0$.