# Minimal Polynomial Degree Inequality for Linear Operator and Its Square

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

I found a problem I got stuck with:

Let $f \in \operatorname{End}(V), V$ be a finite-dimensional $F$-vector space, $F$ algebraically closed.

(a) Let $ a \in F $ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Show: If $(f-a)^{k}=0 $then also $\left(f^{2}-a^{2}\right)^{k}=0 $.

(b) Let $\mu_f$ be the minimal polynomial of $f$ and $\mu_{f^2}$ the minimal polynomial of $f^2$

Show: $\operatorname{deg}\left(\mu_{f^{2}}\right) \leq \operatorname{deg}\left(\mu_{f}\right)$.

I was able to solve (a) but I tried solving (b) since hours now.

I'm sure $\operatorname{deg}\left(\mu_{f^{2}}\right) = \operatorname{deg}\left(\mu_{f}\right)$ holds if $f$ is diagonalizable.

but if $f$ is not diagonalizable, I want to show $\operatorname{deg}\left(\mu_{f^{2}}\right) \leq \operatorname{deg}\left(\mu_{f}\right)$ then.

I know that $\operatorname{deg}\left(\chi_{f^2}\right) =\operatorname{deg}\left(\chi_f\right)$ holds for the characteristic polynomials and $\operatorname{deg}\left(\mu_f\right) + n = \operatorname{deg}\left(\chi_f\right)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N_0}$.

This is all I got so far:

$\operatorname{deg}\left(\mu_{f^{2}}\right) \leq \operatorname{deg}\left(\chi_{f^{2}}\right) = \operatorname{deg}\left(\chi_{f}\right) = \operatorname{deg}\left(\mu_f\right) + n$ $(*)$

Maybe task $(a)$ can help?

I'm expecting the solution to be some kind of equation like in $(*)$ just with a better estimation.

I was able to find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444014/minimal-polynomial-of-squared-operator) but I couldn't go on with that.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Cayley-Hamilton Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem)? This should be useful for you. If this doesn't help, let me know and I can write something more detailed

Comment: Hint: what if you split $\mu_f$ into linear factors over $K$ (which I assume contains $F$) and then apply (a)?

Comment: @blargoner It should be "F" not "K", excuse me for the confusion. I just changed it. I have my $\mu_f$ split into linear factors but I can't see the idea here

Comment: @SamBallas I tried something but can't really tell where Cayley-Hamilton comes useful here. Feel free to elaborate on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the minimal polynomial of $A$ have degree $r$.
$\mathbf 0= m\big(A\big) = \prod_{k=1}^r\big(A-\lambda_kI\big)$
$\implies \mathbf 0=  \prod_{k=1}^r\Big(\big(A-\lambda_kI\big)\big(A+\lambda_kI\big)\Big)=\prod_{k=1}^r\big(A^2-\lambda_k^2 I\big)$
conclude that $A^2$ is annihilated by a degree $r$ polynomial so its minimal polynomial has degree $\leq r$

Comment: It should mean $\mathbf 0= m\big(A\big) = \prod_{k=1}^r\big(A-A\big)$? I thought $\lambda_k$ is the variable

Comment: @MariusLutter I don't know what your comment is trying to say.  There are no "variables" involved, each $\lambda_k \in \mathbb F$.  And $\mathbf 0=\prod_{k=1}^r \mathbf 0$ doesn't tell us anything.  I would hope that you know $A$ has a minimal polynomial of degree $r$ *iff* $\big\{I, A, \cdots, A^{r-1}, A^r\big\}$ is a linearly dependent set and $\big\{I, A, \cdots, A^{r-1}\big\}$ is not. Typically people have some loose familiarity with all this because they have already proven Cayley-Hamilton.    What book are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ satisfies $(f-a)^k=0$ then its minimal polynomial of of the form $(x-a)^{k'}$ for some $k'\leq k$ (I'll come back to this in a minute). Without loss of generality, assume that $k=k'$ and that $(x-a)^k$ is the minimal polynomial.

By part a., you know that $f^2$ is a root of the polynomial $(x-a^2)^k$ and so the minimal polynomial of $f^2$ has degree at most $k$, which is what you wanted to show.

If you want a quick way to verify the claim about the minimal polynomial, put $f$ into Jordan canonical form. The Jordan canonical form is also a root of $(x-a)^k$, from which it is clear that $a$ is the only eigenvalue of $f$. Using the Cayley-Hamilton theorem we see that $a$ is also the only root of the minimal polynomial of $f$

If I wanted to be a bit fancier and not use the algebraically closed hypothesis I would say that the action of $f$ turns $V$ into a $F[x]$-module. Since $F$ is a field then $F[x]$ is a PID. The annihilator of this module consists of all the polynomials for which $f$ is a root and is generated by the minimal polynomial. We know that the annihilator contains $(x-a)^k$ and so this must be a multiple of the minimal polynomial, which must thus be of the form $(x-a)^{k'}$ for $k'\leq k$.

To relate this back to the link you posted in your post notice that if we let $p(x)=(x-a)^k$ and $r(x)=(x-a^2)^k$ then, up to a minus sign, we have $r(x^2)=p(x)p(-x)$

---

---

Comment: Why can we just reduce it to $k \leq k{'}$?  And $r$ is my $\mu_{f^2}$ right?

I got how our minimal polynomial $p(x) = ( x - a)^k$ relates to $r(x^2)$ with $q(x)= r(x^2) = p(x)p(-x) = (-1)^k ( x^2 -a^2)^k \rightarrow r(x) = (-1)^k ( x - a^2)^k$. 

Hence $deg(r(x)) = deg(q(x)) = deg(p(x)p(-x)) = deg(p(x)) + deg (p(-x))$ 

If this is correct so far, I still don't get the catch here.

Comment: The polynomial $r$ is just some polynomial that $f^2$ is a root of, so it may not be the minimal polynomial. However, by definition, the minimal polynomial is the polynomial of lowest degree that $f^2$ is a root of, so the degree of $r$ is an upper bound for the degree of the minimal polynomial.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Hope you don't mind if I tag the other solution as most helpful for me.